# Running non-eggified products against zc.recipe.testrunner

Tags: plone, zope

I have some old products which still work fine with Plone 4.1

These products have unit tests run earlier with `bin/instance test` command.
Since the products are old, they are not packaged as eggs, but used thru `products` buildout directive.

Does `zc.recipe.testrunner` somehow find these products and is it able to execute their unit tests?

Answer (score 3):

No, `zc.recipe.testrunner` can't run non-eggified products. I think it would take less time to [eggify your products](https://weblion.psu.edu/trac/weblion/wiki/EggifyAnExistingProduct) rather then trying some alchemic trick.

Answer (score 1):

If you really, **really** need to do this, add the following to your testrunner section:

```
products = ${instance:products}
initialization =
    import OFS.Application
    import Products
    Products.__path__ = getattr(Products, '__path__', []) + \
        [p.strip() for p in """${:products}""".split('\n') if p.strip()]
    OFS.Application.import_products()
    import App.config
    App.config._config = None
```

This should be considered a last resort and in almost every case, it is preferable to create a proper egg to replace the product.